# WiFi router intermittently show no connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have an old D-Link DIR 600 M router which intermittently drops connection i.e. both wired connection and WiFi from the router shows no connection. Once I reconnect the ISP internet cable to the router, the connection comes back up. I have seen this behavior consistently.

I had a CAT-5E connection which I recently changed to fiber optics connection. The ISP guys told me that this issue would go away once we move to fiber optics, which evidently it did not.

I also increased my router lease time following one of the suggestions here but it didn't help.

I wanted to know:

1. Is it an issue with the ISP?
2. Is it an issue with my router?
3. It it an issue with my router configuration? I can provide more details here.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have one of these D-Links myself and had the same issues.

There is an internal feature called Stateful Packet Inspection (SPI) in these routers. This is ON by default, but it is buggy and gradually fills the entire RAM of the router, causing it to stop forwarding traffic.
When that happens you either have to disconnect the WAN port (which resets this feature) or reboot the router (which also resets it).
Happened every couple of days in my case.

Just disable the feature (it doesn't really add that that much benefit anyway) and the problem should be solved.

In any case you should consider a new router. These D-Links have been out of support (no security updates) for years and they can't handle modern Wifi protocols either.